# asp.net core 2.0 wcf configure binding

Tags: wcf-binding, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I use a asp.net core 2.0 web api with a connected wcf service.
On normal asp.net i can configure the `basicHttpBinding` in the `web.config`. But i can't find any solution to configurate the `basicHttpBinding` in asp.net core.

I have to set the `transferMode="Streamed"` and `maxReceivedMessageSize="128108864"`.

**Edit:** it is a asp.net core 2.0 web api but with a full .net target framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just encountered similar problems. So it seems that web.config is no longer available, because it's only used in IIS, and since Asp.net core 2 doesn't need IIS, web.config is irrelevant. I did try to add it though, but it wouldn't work.

Best thing is to do it programmatically.

```cs
BasicHttpBinding vidiBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
vidiBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000;

EndpointAddress myEndPPtAdd = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9200/SilverlightVidiCloudService");

VidiExternalCloudServiceClient myClient = new VidiExternalCloudServiceClient(vidiBinding, myEndPPtAdd);
await myClient.OpenAsync();
```

Comment: having the same problem